# unable to remove privacy policy page in opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

I want to remove `Privacy Policy` page from footer.

But when I am trying to remove from infromation tab in admin then I am getting error

```
Warning: This information page cannot be deleted as it is currently assigned as the store account terms!
```

How can I remove this page

Comment: Go to admin > Catalog > information > Edit your page > Data Tab > & then Check box Off for Bottom Option(Display in the bottom footer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can remove it from footer by un checking bootm checkbox. But if you want to delete it then first make sure that is it assigned to any terms or not. To check that goto `admin>system>settings>Edit store setting`. There in option tab make sure you have not assigned any information to any terms which are `Account Terms,Checkout Terms,Affiliate Terms and Return Terms`. Then only you will be able to delete it. If you have multiple store then also check for all store too.